# Need to make a group of members who have been members for 5 consecutive years

Tags: civimember, civireport

People who have paid member dues for 5 consecutive years get a discount. We do not have rolling membership.  jan 1 to dec 31 with a grace period of 6 months. I think that due to how the info was imported from our last CRM we cannot run it on dues payment.  We have dues payments that are really donations. It would be good enough to be able to find out who has been a member for the last 5 years and then we can add them to our old list.

I tried doing this in reports with a start date of 1/1/2011 end of 12/31/15 but I get people who joined all during that time.

Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing this:

[image: End Date: <infinity> to 12/31/2015]

Instead, try this:

[image]